# How to set truffle-hdwallet-provider as the Web3 currentProvider inside a web page

Tags: truffle, ethereum-wallet-dapp, web3-providers, hd-wallets

https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-hdwallet-provider/blob/master/README.md provides sample usage for the deployment configuration inside tuffle.js.

I need a sample that update the Web3 currentProvider inside a web page to be used differently with every user (I will use the code upon a user request after generating the mnemonic seed words)

---

Update:

Thanks to @jsantos, and I found it here also: https://gnosis-apollo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pm-js-usage.html.

Actually, it was not mentioned in the documentation that the truffle-hdwallet-provider is compatible with Web3 and could be passed in the constructor. I created a pull request for that: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/pull/1850.
Bellow is the code snippet:

```
var HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");
var mnemonic = "mountains supernatural bird..."; // 12 word mnemonic
var provider = new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "http://localhost:8545");

// Or, alternatively pass in a zero-based address index.
var provider = new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "http://localhost:8545", 5);

// Or, use your own hierarchical derivation path
var provider = new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "http://localhost:8545", 5, 1, "m/44'/137'/0'/0/");


// HDWalletProvider is compatible with Web3. Use it at Web3 constructor, just like any other Web3 Provider
const web3 = new Web3(provider); 

// Or, if web3 is alreay initialized, you can call the 'setProvider' on web3, web3.eth, web3.shh and/or web3.bzz
web3.setProvider(provider)

// ...
// Write your code here.
// ...

// At termination, `provider.engine.stop()' should be called to finish the process elegantly.
provider.engine.stop();
```

Comment: did you try anything yet? post your code. were not going to write it for you.

Comment: After many attempts early, where there are limited documentation and errors wear coming in bulk! I used a different library that is: eth-lightwallet to generate seed words for users! Do you like me to delete this question? Or should I keep it for the community?

Comment: No dont need to delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution is provided [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/8d70mz/using_infura_with_web3_html_providerengine/). Essentially, you build the HDProvider, just as you would in truffle, and then pass it to Web3.

Comment: I used "eth-lightwallet". However, I kept the question and answer for the community to decide whether it is useful or not. Many thanks for your answer. I hope someone will use and validate it.

Comment: You are great, thank you, 
And I found it here also: https://gnosis-apollo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pm-js-usage.html. 
Actually, it was not mentioned in the documentation that the truffle-hdwallet-provider is compatible with Web3 and could be passed in the constructor. I created a pull request for that: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/pull/1850